# jupyter notebook matplotlib\axes\_axes.py error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, axes

I have a problem with `matplotlib\axes\_axes.py`

If i run this:

```
OX = np.linspace(trainX['weight'].quantile(0.01), trainX['weight'].quantile(0.95), 100)
OY =  (-1 * logreg.intercept_[0] - OX * logreg.coef_[0][0])/logreg.coef_[0][1]
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
colors = df['sex'].map({1: 'r', 0: 'b'})
plt.scatter(x = trainX['weight'], y = trainX['height'], c = colors)
rpoint = mpatches.Patch(color = 'red', label = 'Мужчина')
bpoint = mpatches.Patch(color = 'blue', label = 'Женщина')
plt.legend(handles = [rpoint, bpoint])
plt.xlabel('Вес, кг')
plt.ylabel('Рост, см')

plt.plot(OX, OY, color = 'green')
```

then  I get the following error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>       ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py in _parse_scatter_color_args(c, edgecolors, kwargs, xshape, yshape, get_next_color_func)
>          4290                     valid_shape = False
>       -> 4291                     raise ValueError
>          4292             except ValueError:

I think it's all a color issue with c, but i have no idea what i can be done